# Javascript equivalent to "for x in y"

Tags: javascript, python, arraylist

I've been struggling with finding an Javascript equivalent of Python's "for x in y". For instance, I want to push numbers that are even to an empty array, but I don't know how to script the code to do so. I've been doing this:

```
var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var even = []
for(var x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++){
     if(x % 2 == 0){
         even.push(x)
     }
}
```

same thing for strings too if numbers were instead strings:

```
var numbers = [ "one", "two", "three"]
var even = []
for(var x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++){
     if(x == "two"){
         even.push(x)
     }
}
```

i noticed any time I typed it up, it only showed x as the index of the array, but I want to access the elements.

Comment: `numbers[x]` to get the item that belongs to the index `x`

Comment: `for ... of` is the direct idiomatic JS equivalent of Python's `for .. in`. However, for this simple use case, I would prefer simply using the `filter` method on the array - with no loop whatsoever.

Comment: What's wrong with `for(let x of [1,2,3]) { console.log(x) }`

Comment: @RandyCasburn `for/in` should only be used on objects, not arrays because it iterates all own properties, not just indexed ones.

Comment: @RandyCasburn it prints the indexes for a start. [It's also not advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Wow you guys are fast - yes - please use `for...of`

Comment: That was a case of "ready, fire, aim" :-)

Comment: @RandyCasburn We were locked and loaded!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (let x of numbers)` JS [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is what you are looking for.

`x` will be iterating over the values and not indexes.

```
const numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const even = []
for(const x of numbers){
     if(x % 2 === 0){
         even.push(x)
     }
}
```

**P.S.**

`even = numbers.filter(el => el % 2 === 0)` can be also used and is much simpler.

You can find the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Almost all browsers except IE support this.

Answer (score 0):

When you push x to the list, it will push 2,4,...,length of the first list. You need to use

```
var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var even = []
for(var x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++){
    if(x % 2 == 0){
        even.push(numbers[x])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [a generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and [a `for..of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) you can achieve something quite similar to the Python syntax.

```js
function* filter(predicate, iterable) {
  for (let item of iterable)
    if (predicate(item))
      yield item;
}

const isEven = x => x % 2 === 0;


var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var even = []
for(let x of filter(isEven, numbers)){
  even.push(x)
}

console.log(even);
```

For more information, you can check [the MDN article on iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).